# Linear Nodes to optimize and solve problems in java

Tags: java, algorithm, queue, nodes, shortest-path

Ultimately I honestly want this as a puzzle-solver, but I figure I can modify this for other purposes as well...I'm trying to find the shortest chain of words between a start word and end word, changing one letter at a time. I'm doing this with Linear Nodes and LinkedQueues.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver
{
    static LinkedQueue<LinearNode<String>> open = new LinkedQueue<LinearNode<String>>();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a four letter start word: ");
    String start = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter a four letter end word: ");
    String end = input.next();
    System.out.println();
    input.close();

    if (start.equals(end))
    {
        System.out.println("The words are the same.\nThe chain length is 0.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(findChain(start, end));
    }
}

public static String findChain(String start, String end)
{
    boolean finalFound = false;
    Dictionary dict = new Dictionary("four.txt");
    char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
            'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    LinearNode<String> begin = new LinearNode<String>(start);
    ArrayList<String> used = new ArrayList<String>();
    used.add(start);
    open.enqueue(begin);

    while((!open.isEmpty()) && (!finalFound))
    {
        LinearNode<String> currentNode = open.dequeue();
        String currentWord = currentNode.getElement();
        char[] charStr = currentWord.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < charStr.length; i++)
        {
            for (char ch : alphabet)
            {
                char[] charStr2 = charStr.clone();
                charStr2[i] = ch;
                String newWord = new String(charStr2);

                if (dict.contains(newWord) && (!used.contains(newWord)))
                {
                    used.add(newWord);
                    LinearNode<String> newNode = new LinearNode<String>(newWord, currentNode);
                    open.enqueue(newNode);
                    if (newWord.equals(end))
                    {
                        finalFound = true;
                        i = 4;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (finalFound == true)
    {
        String str = "";
        LinkedStack<String> stack = new LinkedStack<String>();

        while (!open.isEmpty())
        {
            stack.push(open.dequeue().toString());
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < stack.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            str += stack.pop() + "\n";
        }
        return str;
    }
    else
        return "No chain found";
    }
}


    public class LinkedQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T>
    {
        private int count;
        private LinearNode<T> front, rear;

        public LinkedQueue()
        {
            count = 0;
            front = rear = null;
        }

        public void enqueue(T element)
        {
            LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element);

            if (isEmpty())
                front = node;
            else 
                rear.setNext(node);

            rear = node;
            count++;
        }

        @Override
        public T dequeue() throws EmptyCollectionException
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("queue");

            T result = front.getElement();
            front = front.getNext();
            count--;

            if (isEmpty())
                rear = null;

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public T first()
        {
            return front.getElement();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return (count == 0);
        }

        @Override
        public int size()
        {
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
           {
              String result = "";
              LinearNode<T> current = front;

              while (current != null)
              {
                 result = result + (current.getElement()).toString() + "\n";
                 current = current.getNext();
              }

              return result;
           }

    }


public class LinkedStack<T> implements StackADT<T>
{
    private int count;
    private LinearNode<T> top;

    public LinkedStack()
    {
        setCount(0);
        top = null;
    }

    public void push(T element)
    {
        LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        temp.setNext(top);
        top = temp;
        setCount(getCount() + 1);

    }

    public T pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

        T result = top.getElement();
        top = top.getNext();
        setCount(getCount() - 1);

        return result; 
    }

    public T peek()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

        T result = top.getElement();

        return result;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (getCount() == 0);
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return getCount();
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please specify what is the problem you are having.

Comment: @afzalex it's outputting tons of seemingly random words, which I suspect is a list of every word it decided was a real word along the way, rather than the solution to the problem of shortest chain.

Comment: Have you created your own `LinkedQueue`, `LinkedStack`, `Dictionary`? And if it is so, then why are you not using standard `Collection framework`. And why do you think that without looking at your those code someone can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I know those are all working properly.  Dictionary is simply an object that contains an arrayList but I wanted to have a custom object because it made more sense to me.  As for why I didn't include that, it'd be like 400 lines of code, and I know most of StackOverflow community hates that.

Comment: I've added more code, as requested, but left out the interfaces, for obvious reasons.  I realize there's an indent error in the middle of all this but i'm trying to copy/paste from eclipse >.>